# Fabric.JS and AngularJS – difference between 0 and '0'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fabricjs

I am creating my FabricJS objects with some usual attributes like "width", "height" etc. like this:

```
var textSample = new fabric.Textbox(text.slice(0, getRandomInt(0, text.length)), {
    includeDefaultValues: true,
    fontSize: 20,
    left: getRandomInt(350, 400),
    top: getRandomInt(350, 400),
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    fill: '#000000',
    fontWeight: '',
    originX: 'left',
    width: 300,
    hasRotatingPoint: true,
    centerTransform: true,
    name: "Text",
    icon: "format-size",
    fontWeight: 400,
    charSpacing: '0',
    angle: '0',
    strokeWidth: 0
});
```

Havin some problems with the "zero" values.

For the "angle": If I am using

```
angle: '0',
```

everything is fine (in terms of displaying this in my custom number input.

```
angle: 0,
```

will not display the value "zero" in my numberinput

Using this for "strokeWidth" on the other side will break my Textbox and will display the contents only if I change the value manually:

```
strokeWidth: '0'
```

Comment: check this for [strokeWidth](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#strokeWidth) and this for [angle](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#strokeWidth) both are accepting type number as value. If you have string value you need to parse using `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`.

Comment: @Ramesh Rajendran Thanks guys – the initial scope of my question is answered by you both. I understand now the differnce (even if this is trivial for developers). My essential problem seems to be caused by my custom widget. I am using this wonderful widget toolkit for my application: [ https://xel-toolkit.org/ ]. Unfortunately the very talented developer of the Xel-Toolkit has no Angular knowledge, nor the time for Angular problems. Anyhow: Here this part of my project in a fiddle:  [ https://jsfiddle.net/sharksinn/1z58rjt9/29/ ] – Latest Chrome only!

Comment: Its working right?

Comment: Just have a look at the fiddle if you have some spare time. It makes the problem clearer (especially the problem with the xel-toolkit which seems to be the major one) ...

Answer (score 1):

### difference between 0 and '0'

- 0 - is a integer value (number)
- '0' - is a character value(string)

> In fabric.js, the `angle` property only accept number's. You should parse the string '0' to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle code is using this for sending the values in fabricjs:

```
        $element.on('change keyup select', function () {
            if ($element[0].type !== 'checkbox') {
                $scope[setter] && $scope[setter](this.value);
            }
        });
```

this.value is a String.
To get the number from it you need to parse the value.
Since you have few element types and probably many setters, would be better to execute the conversion in the setters so that for each setter you can use the specific type you need.

Comment: Andrea, the code is almost a 1:1 from the kitchensink example – excepting that I'm using the Xel-Toolkit. I think you are refering to this part of the code (where the value is defined as Int): `$scope.setStrokeWidth = function(value) {
    setActiveStyle('strokeWidth', parseInt(value, 10));
  };` – I have tried everything, but my values for the strokeWidth are not reflected. No matter if I am using Float or Int. On the other side if I connect the input and the slider to the angle attribute, everything is working. Is there maybe something wrong in the code part where I am getting the style?

Comment: what does setActiveStyle does? because is not a fabric thing.

Comment: The setActiveStyle was defined in the kitchensink example (the one from fabricjs.com). Apparently it is setting the style attributes for the object. The definition is in the js you can see in the fiddle...